# remove wordpress yoast seo plugin meta keywords from custom pages

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom template page using WordPress Template redirect. 
Now my problem is WP Yoast SEO Plugin is doing page analysis and placing meta tags with page not found values.

I want to disable WP Yoast SEO page analysis on my custom page. I tried to follow the API for this plugin [in this link](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/) and used the following in my theme's `functions.php` but no luck

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_metakey', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: What does "no luck" means? Does it work, does it not work?

Comment: It does not work......

Comment: Sorry, I mean does it produce any effect? Of removing *all* keywords *everywhere*?

Comment: no it has no effect on output I can see all the meta tags related to yoast seo

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_metakeywords', '__return_false');
```

You can find a good overview [here](https://solvemethod.com/remove-yoast-seo-meta-tags/).